# java.lang.SecurityException on takePersistableUriPermission() (SAF)

Tags: java, android, android-intent, sd-card, securityexception

I'm using the Storage Access Framework to get write access on the sd-card (API >= 21).

It works fine on most devices, but some like the Galaxy S7 (Edge, API 23) throw an SecurityException when calling takePersistableUriPermission().

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: No persistable permission grants found for UID 10150 and Uri 0 @ content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/70CD-6B92
```

code:

```
//call the SAF
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, Config.REQUEST_SAF);

//Persist permissions
int flags = resultData.getFlags();
flags &= (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

this.getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(treeUri, flags); //throws exception
```

The exception doesn't occur on all S7 devices. I've tested the code successfully on 2 devices but this one throws the SecurityException.

May i have to add some flags to the call of the SAF?

```
intent.addFlags(
Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION |
Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION |
Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?

Comment: Not yet. Seems like nobody knows where it comes from.

Comment: I am facing the same issue on Samsung devices. @Farasy Did you find any solution of this problem ? I posted the question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74369880/securityexception-using-storage-access-framework-in-some-devices

Comment: @Smeet Unfortunately no persistent solution found. However, this is a non common issue and on certain devices only.

Answer (score 6):

I tried adding `grantUriPermission` before `takePersistableUriPermission` and it's the only thing that worked for me to avoid the error thrown by the system `SecurityException`:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
try {
    getContext().grantUriPermission(getContext().getPackageName(), uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    // on Kitkat api only 0x3 is allowed (FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
    getContext().grantUriPermission(getContext().getPackageName(), uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
} catch (SecurityException e) {
    Log.e("", e.toString());
}

try {
    int takeFlags = intent.getFlags();
    takeFlags &= (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    getContext().getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, takeFlags);
} catch (SecurityException e) {
    Log.e("", e.toString());
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll give it a try.

Comment: I applied the same logic but still it is not working @box on some of the Samsung, Vivo and Oppo devices.

Answer (score -1):

try adding this [flag](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION):

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried but no luck with this.