# ContentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission() has no documented error possible yet evidently can occur

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

I've had success using

```
getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(myUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

to allow for access to a document across reboots (previously obtained using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT).

But I wonder what happens if it fails as there is no return value and there is no documented exceptions (checked or otherwise) as shown here: [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver#takePersistableUriPermission(android.net.Uri,%20int)).

Yet when searching on SO I see there is in fact a `SecurityException` possible shown here:
[exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37993762/java-lang-securityexception-on-takepersistableuripermission-saf).  And it would stand to reason there are errors possible, for example an invalid URI provided - or document no longer exists, etc.

So the question is how to properly handle **undocumented** `RuntimeException`s which evidently may occur on this call.  Are these the only valid approaches?

(A)

```
try {
    getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(myUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); 
} catch (SecurityException e) {
   // handle failure to get persistable permission though NOT DOCUMENTED
}
```

(B)

```
try {
    getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(myUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); 
} catch (Exception e) {
   // handle failure to get persistable permission
}
```

And more specifically is there any way to find out all possible `RuntimeException`s from this call ?

Comment: You will just catch all exceptions you heard they were once thrown. I think it is only this security exception.

Answer (score 0):

> Are these the only valid approaches?

You could catch `Throwable` instead of `SecurityException` or `Exception`. But, in general, `try`/`catch` is how you would catch whatever is thrown.

> And more specifically is there any way to find out all possible `RuntimeExceptions` from this call ?

Not realistically. There are tens of thousands of Android device models, and any of them could contain modifications to Android that affect what gets thrown by the code paths behind `takePersistableUriPermission()`.